# how to display an image on webpage in php which is retrieved using python?

Tags: php, reference

```
    import socket
import pygame
import sys

host = "10.0.0.13"
port=5000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,240),0)


while True:
    clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientsocket.connect((host, port))
    received = []
    # loop .recv, it returns empty string when done, then transmitted data is completely received
    while True:
        #print("esperando receber dado")
        recvd_data = clientsocket.recv(230400)
        if not recvd_data:
            break
        else:
            received.append(recvd_data)

    dataset = ''.join(received)
    image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(320,240),"RGB") # convert received image from string
    screen.blit(image,(0,0)) # "show image" on the screen
    pygame.display.update()

    # check for quit events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Actually what i want to do is like i want to accept an image from the client and to display it.This code is displaying the image in python but i want to display it in a web browser using Php.Please someone suggest me the code and the proper way to do this.

Comment: image upload using php  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Googling shows a few Python to PHP converters. Run it through one of those, use your knowledge of PHP to get it working. If still stuck, post again to this site, with your code and an explanation of what it going wrong, with error message, and what you have done to try to correct it.